# process data on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a scenario where I am uploading a text file then providing a user input and then according to the user input processing further.

Sample file :

```
DOWN 07.09.2016 08:21:33 - 07.09.2016 08:23:33
UP   07.11.2016 09:41:07 - 09.11.2016 09:20:33
DOWN 09.11.2016 08:26:33 - 09.11.2016 08:46:33
UP   09.11.2016 08:23:33 - 09.11.2016 08:25:33
DOWN 09.11.2016 08:36:33 - 09.11.2016 08:41:33
DOWN 10.11.2016 08:36:33 - 10.11.2016 08:39:33
```

code :

```
try:
    import Tkinter as Tk
    import tkFileDialog as fileDialog
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as Tk
    import tkinter.filedialog as fileDialog

import datetime



def read_data():
    '''
    Read data from file and convert to list with datetime
    which can be used to calculate time and display.
    '''
    global data

    filename = fileDialog.askopenfilename()

    if filename:
        # read all lines
        with open(filename) as fileHandle:
            lines = fileHandle.readlines()

        # convert to `datetime` (not `timestamp`)
        data = []        
        for line in lines:
            #direction = line[:4].strip()
            #dt1 = line[5:24]
            #dt2 = line[27:46]

            direction, d1, t1, _, d2, t2 = line.split()
            dt1 = d1 + ' ' + t1
            dt2 = d2 + ' ' + t2 

            t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt1, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
            t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt2, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

            seconds = (t2-t1).seconds

            data.append([direction, t1, t2, seconds])

        print(data)


def processText(lines, selected_date):

    total = 0
    start = None

    print(selected_date)
    # if there is `selected_date` then convert to `datetime`
    if selected_date:
        try:
            selected_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(selected_date, "%d.%m.%Y")
        except AttributeError as ex:
            print("ERROR:", ex)
            selected_date = None

    # calculate time
    for direction, t1, t2, seconds in lines:

        if direction == "DOWN":

            # if `selected_date` then filter times
            if selected_date and t1 <= selected_date:
                continue

            if not start:
                start = t1.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

            total += seconds

    # convert to minutes after summing all second
    total = total//60

    return total, start

def calculate():

    all_dates = entry.get().split(',')
    print(all_dates)
    all_dates = [date.strip() for date in all_dates]

    txt = ''

    for current_date in all_dates:
        down, start = processText(data, current_date)
        txt += "Total Downtime is {0} min from {1}\n".format(down, start)

    textVar.set(txt)

# --- main ---

data = None # to keep data from file

# -

root = Tk.Tk()

button = Tk.Button(root, text="Open", command=read_data)
button.grid(column=1, row=1)

textVar = Tk.StringVar(root)

label = Tk.Label(root, textvariable=textVar)
label.grid(column=1, row=2)

entry = Tk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(column=1, row=3)

button2 = Tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=calculate)
button2.grid(column=1, row=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Above code prompts me to select date in format Date1.Month1.Year1,Date2.Month2.Year2 ... (depending on the number input for date.)

and returns output as :

```
 Total Downtime is x min from date1.month1.year1 xx:xx:xx(time1)
 Total Downtime is y min from date2.month2.year2 yy:yy:yy(time2)
```

Here I have the details of downtime in mins and i want to convert that in percentage till date. For example ->

user input :

1.9.2016,1.11.2016,1.1.2016

Output :

```
 Total Downtime is 30 min from 1.9.2016 08:21:33 & Availability percentage from selected date to till date : xx.xxx% 
 Total Downtime is 28 min from 1.11.2016 08:26:33 & Availability percentage from selected date to till date : yy.yyy%
 Total Downtime is 30 min from 1.11.2016 08:26:33 & Availability percentage from selected date to till date : zz.zzz%
```

logic behind availability calculation would be

```
total number of min down from date(which is retrieved)/total number of min till date * 100
```

I am stuck in this part, Is this achievable?  Any help would be great!!

Comment: yes it achievable - you have to add all minutes first. Do you have problem to add minutes ? BTW: if you execut `processText()` with `None` instead of `selected_date` then you get "total number of all minutes". And then you can substract "total minutes from selected date" to get "total minutes till selected date"

Comment: You should provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your entire code.

Comment: Yes , I don't know how should I proceed to get total number of minutes till selected date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `processText()` with `None` instead of date then you get total number of minutes when it was down

```
total_down, start = processText(data, None)
```

and you can use it to calculate percentage.

```
percentage = (down/total_down) * 100
```

and you can use string formatting `{:.2f}` to display only two digits after dot

```
def calculate():

    all_dates = entry.get().split(',')
    print(all_dates)
    all_dates = [date.strip() for date in all_dates]

    # calculate total number of minutes when it was down
    total_down, start = processText(data, None) # <-- None

    print('total_down:', total_down)

    txt = ''

    for current_date in all_dates:
        down, start = processText(data, current_date)

        # calculate percetage
        percentage = (down/total_down) * 100

        # use string formatting {:.2f} to display only two digits after dot
        txt += "Total Downtime is {} min from {} ({:.2f}%)\n".format(down, start, percentage)

    textVar.set(txt)
```

[image]

---

If you want total number of minutes when it was down or up then you have to change `processText` and add new parameter (ie. `word`) which will check if `direction` is `DOWN` or `UP` or both (`word = None`)

```
def processText(lines, selected_date, word="DOWN"):

    total = 0
    start = None

    print(selected_date)
    # if there is `selected_date` then convert to `datetime`
    if selected_date:
        try:
            selected_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(selected_date, "%d.%m.%Y")
        except AttributeError as ex:
            print("ERROR:", ex)
            selected_date = None

    # calculate time
    for direction, t1, t2, seconds in lines:

        if not word or word == direction:

            # if `selected_date` then filter times
            if selected_date and t1 <= selected_date:
                continue

            if not start:
                start = t1.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

            total += seconds

    # convert to minutes after summing all second
    total = total//60

    return total, start

def calculate():

    all_dates = entry.get().split(',')
    print(all_dates)
    all_dates = [date.strip() for date in all_dates]

    # calculate total number of minutes when it was down and up
    total_down, start = processText(data, None, None)

    print('total_down:', total_down)

    txt = ''

    for current_date in all_dates:
        down, start = processText(data, current_date, "DOWN")
        percentage = (down/total_down) * 100
        txt += "Total Downtime is {} min from {} ({:.2f}%)\n".format(down, start, percentage)

    textVar.set(txt)
```

Comment: see code - it calculate `total_down` and later it uses this value to calculate `percentage` and it uses `{:.2f}` to display percentage with two digits after dot.

Comment: here i have selected date > 12.9.2016 
This provides down time as 2.07% but according to calculation logic it should provide 99.07%

Comment: screen shot that you have attached is for the 2nd answer or first answer ?

Comment: screenshot is for first version - so I put it after first code.

Comment: second version calculate total number of minutes when it was down and up - so it gives smaller value. But if you use word "DOWN" in `total_down, start = processText(data, None, "DOWN")` then you can get the same result. Second version is more universal and it is useful if you want also to calculate time when it was UP.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but according to calculation it gives me 100% when it is not can I get precise values and not rounded off values when its 99.9997 it shows me 100% as its rounded off

Comment: then use `{}` instead of `{:.2f}` and you get `99.9997` but  then you can  get also `93.33333333333333` (or use `{:.4f}` to get always 4 digits)